# Quantity increment button

Tags: php, quantity, magento2.1.6

I have configured a product with the "Qty increments" (100) / and " Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" (100).
When I go to the product page, the quantity is 100 by default but when I click on "+", the quantity is increase to 101 and not 200.
[image]

[image]

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use bootstrap on your website then let me know, I have solution for this

Comment: Yes, I used the "Porto" theme from ThemeForest. It's a bootstrap theme.

Comment: did you got the solution or Should I need to post the answer?

Comment: No, I didn't find the solution. Can you post it? Thanks

Comment: please wait , will post in 30 mints , thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here I am guiding you adding plus/minus functionality with increment of 100 in default file. Use the code accordingly.

In catalog module edit your Quantity function which comes by default in **addtocart.phtml** like below code

```
<div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Update the code  below adding **class** to input field and pass input id/name to buttons **data field and for**

```
<div class="field qty">

                <div class="control qty-numbers">
                    <div class="input-group">


                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number quantity-left-minus"  data-type="minus" data-field="qty">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>


                        <input type="number"
                        name="qty"
                        class="form-control input-number"
                        id="qty"
                        min="1"
                        maxlength="12"
                         value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                                 title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                                 data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                                 />


                        <!--plus button-->
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number quantity-left-plus" data-type="plus" data-field="qty">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

do it carefully and then add below script in bootstrap.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var quantitiy=100;
   $('.quantity-right-plus').click(function(e){

        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var quantity = parseInt($('#qty').val());

        // If is not undefined

            $('#qty').val(quantity + 100);


            // Increment

    });

     $('.quantity-left-minus').click(function(e){
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the field name
        var quantity = parseInt($('#qty').val());

        // If is not undefined

            // Increment
            if(quantity>100){
            $('#qty').val(quantity - 100);
            }
    });

});
```

This works on default, if doesn't work with your then please pass me the quantity or add to cart code.

I hope this solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a question, I have a lot of product with different incremant quantity. For this article, I need to increase the value from 100 to 200, but for example, on another product, the value have to increase one by one. Is it working with your code?

Comment: this require more customization and I haven't tested that way.  Currently this code is for you current requirement . if this fulfill that then I will check that case too if possible today , I help you out

Comment: I just tested that way and it works with little tweaks in the code . Test this first if it works then I will help you out for that case too

Comment: I post under the custom addtocart.phtml file that my website use to increase the value of the qty when I click on "+/-". Sorry for the mistake

Comment: use that file i sent and ( your theme custom file , right ?) , I hope you have added js in your bootstrap.js...

Comment: your bootstrap js location is app\design\frontend\Smartwave\porto\web\bootstrap\js

Comment: please check update .phtml file code . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have customized the (+) and (-) increments in product details page. You should fetch the database value qty increments and assign to your (+) and (-). Then it will be incremented as you excepted.

Hope it will help you!

If possible please share your code.

Answer (score 1):

catalog_product_view:

```
<container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                </container>
```

addtocart.phtml:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Custom addtocart.phtml file :

```
<div class="box-tocart">
<div class="fieldset">
    <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
    <div class="field qty">
        <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="number"
                   name="qty"
                   id="qty"
                   maxlength="12"
                   value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                   title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                   data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                   />
        </div>
        <div class="qty-changer">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-inc"><i class="porto-icon-up-dir"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-dec"><i class="porto-icon-down-dir"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="submit"
                title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                class="action primary tocart"
                id="product-addtocart-button">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
        </button>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```